# Cursor reuse in DB2 embedded in C

Tags: sql, c, db2

Heyo,

So I'm trying to embed some SQL in C but I have a problem where the first time the code is executed, it works but every subsequent time, it return returns null.

My code is structured such that I have the query in a function, which gets called multiple times.

The function: declares the cursor, OPENs, loops with FETCH, then CLOSES.  Is there a step I'm missing so I can then run the query again later?

I need to redeclare because the query is based on a value passed into the function.

Thanks
-Mitchell

Comment: i could be wrong but you might need to DEALLOCATE the cursor

Comment: According to the SQL processors, there is no such command as DEALLOCATE

Comment: Odd here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188782.aspx

Comment: I think the database I'm hitting is an Oracle DB2 instance running on Linux

Comment: Not sure when I've called sql stored procedures in a loop in c# i have had to close then reestablish the connection each time but that honestly might not have anything to do with it never dealt with oracle

Comment: _Oracle DB2 instance_? This is new. You'd probably need to show us the code to have a chance for a meaningful suggestion.

Comment: So I could never get it to work in a function. I ended up just embedding the code directly in the loop and that fixed the issue